# Basic variable declaration and memory in Javascript/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory, vuejs2

I have a very basic question about declaring variable in Javascript/Vue.

```
function myFunction () {
  let myVars = this.myVars;
  forEach(myVars, (var) => {
    // Do something with var
  } 
}
```

VS

```
function myFunction () {
  forEach(this.myVars, (var) => {
    // Do something with var
  } 
}
```

I was wondering if the first style of coding would waste so much resources to the point that it affect performance in modern computer/browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no impact on performance here.
When the `myFunction` is called, `myVars` is registered in the function scope.
Then you make `myVars` refer to `this.myVars`, if the value in `this.myVars` is an array or object, then there is no deep copy operation here. Both are referring to the same object.
Finally, when the function execution completes, the scope created is destroyed so no memory leaks there.

One suggestion though is to prefer `const` over `let` over `var`.